# Updating Excel document with macros

Tags: excel, office365, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api, xlsm

Using the Microsoft Graph API with Office 365, I've not been able to update a `.xlsm` file with macros, even if all I'm changing is a row of data.

If I open the file in the web version of Excel (Office 365) and make an editable copy and re-save

The same command for a `.xlsx` file is fine.

OneDrive identifies a change has happened as the modified date changes, and the desktop app re-syncs the files.

In the web version, you can create an editable version and then when you download that file to the desktop the macros still exist.

If it isn't possible to normally modify the file, is it possible to emulate this behavior?